# Cordova navigator.notification.confirm callback function doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm testing my first Cordova application (Cordova version 5.1.1).

navigator.notification.confirm callback function runs fine on Chrome with Ripple, but not on a smartphone with Android 2.3.6.

```
var scheda = {
    send: function() {
        navigator.notification.confirm("Confermi l'invio delle schede?",
            scheda.confirmedSend, "Conferma invio", ["Si", "No"]);
    },

    confirmedSend: function(buttonIndex) {
        navigator.notification.alert(buttonIndex,
            function() {}, "Informazione", "OK");
    }
}
```

In Chrome I get both dialog boxes, on Android only the first one.

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: I've just tested and it's working on my device, maybe there is some problem with android 2.3.6

Comment: Just tested on Android 4.1.2, it works. In platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml minSdkVersion is 10 (that is Android 2.3.3), as per Cordova default installation. Must I limit the range of Android platforms, removing the oldest ones? What minimum version should I choose?

Comment: For latest cordova version you need minSDK 14 (android 4.0.0), you can use that